# setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); Android doesn't work

Tags: android, textview, margins

I have this code, but the textview are all without Margin right and i don't know why.
I add some lines of onCreate for declaration.
And the functions about the creation of the textview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_materia);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_materia);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("New text");
/*
 * add textview from editext
 */
private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
        }
    };
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lparams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 0);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    return textView;
}
```

some helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried referencing Relative Layout Params or Linear Layout Params depending on what is set in your XML?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong.
I deleted "final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);"
And added the reference to Linear Layout params and now work.
But now how linear layout takes the code? All linearlayout?

Comment: its ok, I have made this mistake hundreds of times. you can reference a different one if it is a Relative Layout. You would do the exact same thing just with Relative rather than Linear. This method works if you have a layout within a layout. So if you have a Linear as the parent and a Relative as the child or vice versa.

Comment: So the LinearLayout.LayoutParams take all the LinearLayout from the Activity?
Ty for help ;)

Comment: yes :) I'm not sure how to use simply "LayoutParams". I know that you have to implicitly define which type of layout you are using before you use LayoutParams though!